# Can a Stream be sequentially processed for part of the pipeline, and then as parallel?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code which does not work as I intended (a random line, instead of the first, is skipped):

```
Files.lines(path)
     .skip(1)
     .parallel()
     .forEach( System.out::println )
```

I have a feeling I misunderstood the behavior of Streams. The question is: Can I first treat a stream as sequential (and use "stateful intermediate operations") and then feed it into a parallel `forEach`?

Comment: You are doing a linear operation, why are you using `.parallel()`?

Comment: @Esko Obviously, the "println" is a stand-in for a processor-intensive operation that I do as function of the entries in a file.

Comment: sheitt [embarrased] my runtime is not executing them in parallel...!

Comment: Turns out that my jUnit tests do not execute in parallel (not sure why??) but non-tests do. Completely confused me! Anyways, the behaviour of skip is very unpredicatble is seems, sometimes it is the very last item that is skipped. And even parallel() is wonky ... sometimes the threads are only created if the number of iterations is high and the number of items in the list is high. For slow jobs (that take a lot of computing) it did not create any threads. For 1000+ short jobs (milliseconds to do) it did execute in parallel. Test and see.

Comment: Looking at the Javadoc, I think what you want is `forEachOrdered`. And then the skip will work properly and the stream will be parallel. However, you will still have to endure a very unpredictable and uncontrollable Threads generation formula. Better to roll your own. Unless, like I tried and works, you have many short lived tasks, then it seems to work.

Comment: @SaintHill Does `forEachOrdered` affect the forEach itself? I think it does, and disables parallelism. mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-June/010126.html

Comment: My test shows that it spawned a single thread. But then the spawned thread did all (all) the work. That was a little pointless ...

Answer (score 2):

The entire pipeline is either parallel of sequential.

Try using `forEachOrdered` instead of `forEach`. In my test it skips the first line if `forEachOrdered` is used (with `forEach` it skips the last line).

`forEach` ignores encounter order and it seems that is also can make other operations to ignore it.

Comment: Do you have any source for this information? Maybe with more details?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, but a feature. Calling `parallel()` makes the whole stream parallel. Unless a subsequent call to `sequential()` is made, which sets the whole stream back to sequential mode.

[The javaodoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) says:

> Returns an equivalent stream that is parallel.

Comment: How could I achieve the desired behavior without dumping everything to an intermediate collection?

Comment: I guess you could use `StreamSupport.stream(Files.lines(path).skip(1).spliterator(), true)`. Not tested though.

Comment: It's that ineligant? Did it not occur to anyone that it might be a good idea to execute a part of the operations on a stream sequentially, for semantic and performance reasons?

Comment: It's also very surprising behavior that later chained calls drastically alter the semantics of preceding ones.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky: Actually, switching a pipeline from parallel to sequential and back used to be possible, but was changed relatively late in the stream design.  I touch on it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603187/3614835), with some comments by Brian Goetz himself.  You could probably find the mailing list post detailing the change if you're still interested to know why.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. However your code should *probably* work as intended, from the [`Stream.skip` javadocs](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-)

> > While skip() is generally a cheap operation on sequential stream pipelines, it can be quite expensive on ordered parallel pipelines, especially for large values of n, since skip(n) is constrained to skip not just any n elements, but the first n elements in the encounter order. Using an unordered stream source (such as generate(Supplier)) or removing the ordering constraint with BaseStream.unordered() may result in significant speedups of skip() in parallel pipelines, if the semantics of your situation permit. If consistency with encounter order is required, and you are experiencing poor performance or memory utilization with skip() in parallel pipelines, switching to sequential execution with BaseStream.sequential() may improve performance.

Whether your code works or doesnt depends on the nature of the stream returned by `Files.lines(..)`, it depends if that stream is `Ordered`. These characteristics are set by the Spliterator that is used, if the stream is ordered, then it will always skip the first element. if the stream is unordered, then it will skip one element.

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

Comment: I can't find a way to check if the stream is ordered (is there reall no way?), but in the source code of `Files.lines` I see a `Spliterator.ORDERED`. Also, why would someone call `skip` on an unordered stream? Why doesn't it just throw an exception?

Comment: you can still skip the first element, even if the elements dont have a natural Ordering.

Comment: why in the world would I skip a *random* element?

Comment: i cant think of a good use case, but its better than throwing an exception.

Comment: Throwing an exception when an operation that expects a sequential stream (or ordered parallel? -- although I'm not sure that makes any difference) is applied to a parallel stream is the appropriate behavior according to the philosophies of Java.

Comment: well thats the thing, skip() doesnt expect an Ordered stream, it works on all types of streams. same goes for all the other stream functions. the designers wanted to create a class of functions that work on sequential and parallel streams, but whose behavior (for optimized execution) could change based on the nature (characteristics) of the stream. you can make certain combinations of calls that lead to some non intuitive behavior, but if you really want to know the reasons why it was implemented this way (straight from the horses mouth), i suggest you read the lambda dev mail archives.

Comment: I can't say if all "stateful intermediate operations" don't have meaning in the context of a parallel stream, but it's certainly the case for `skip()` (and, eg, for my `map(byOverlappingPairs)` I discussed in another question). An annotation should mark such operations and flag them when they're used in a parallel stream (likely causing unintended, nondeterministic behavior). The alternate view I've heard, that all operations should be stateless, is untenable. I don't need to design everything for parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that skip(n) does not skip the first n elements on a parallel stream.

Solution, chomp the first [n] lines off using the BufferedReader readLine() method.

Then obtain the Stream which will carry on where you left off with the reader:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestStreams {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
         unordered();
    }

    public static void unordered() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(n -> sb.append(n).append("\n"));

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sb.toString()))) {
            if (br.readLine() != null) {
                br.lines()
                        .parallel()
                        .forEach(it -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " : " + it));
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: this seems to directly contradict the javadocs for the `skip(long)` method. looks like a bug. http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-