# Java 8 Streams, perform part of the work as parallel stream and the other as sequential stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream performing a series of operations in parallel, then I have to write the results into a file, so I need the writing operation to be sequential, but it needs to be performed as a stream, I have lots of data to write, I cannot use an intermediate collection.
Is there a way to do that?

I thought to a solution that doesn't seem very clean, that is to make the writing method synchronized. Is this approach the only possible? is there some other way?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, why do things in parallel, then, if writing is the bottleneck? Synchronizing file writes will take just as much time; you shouldn't bother. That is, unless your file is record based and each record has a fixed length.

Comment: Writing is not the bottleneck, it's just that if I do it not sequentially records can be written in an iterleaved way. Actually the bottleneck is the generation part which is reading from an XML stream I guess. I will try to compare a sequential computation vs parallel computation with syncronized writing then I will tell you which performs better.

Comment: Sorry, probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640157/can-a-stream-be-sequentially-processed-for-part-of-the-pipeline-and-then-as-par

Comment: @fge I have run the test, sequential takes 28 minutes, parallel with syncronized writing takes 10 minutes.

Comment: Then it appears that writing is not really the bottleneck... Your computation seems quite heavy ;) How do you synchronize writes? Do you submit data to write to a `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: No, I've only made the writing method `synchronized`.

Comment: can't be done: stream.parallel()./*whateve*/.sequential()./* write file */? i'm little confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to turn a `Stream` to *sequential* in order to perform a sequential terminal operation. See, for example, the documentation of [`Stream.forEachOrdered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> This operation processes the elements one at a time, in encounter order if one exists. Performing the action for one element [*happens-before*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) performing the action for subsequent elements, but for any given element, the action may be performed in whatever thread the library chooses.

In other words, the action may be called by different threads as a result of the parallel processing of the previous steps, but it is guaranteed to be thread safe, does not call the action concurrently and even maintains the order if the stream was *ordered*.

So there is no need to do any additional synchronization if you use `forEachOrdered` to specify the write to a file as terminal operations.

Similar guarantees apply to other terminal operations regarding certain functions. It’s critical to study the documentation of the specific operation and to understand which guarantees are made and what is left unspecified.

Comment: The performance are more or less the same with `synchronized` but it is the best way to do that for sure.